# How to call redirect function manually in django from client?

Tags: javascript, django

Home page on my django site are loading via this function:

```
def homePage(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login')
    else:
        return render_to_response('homeTemplate.html',c)
```

It's call when client goes to site from address line.

How to call this function manualy (by click)?

```
$('#goHome').click(function(){
    //execute homePage
})
```

Comment: This is completely unclear. What does "call this manually (by click)" mean?

Comment: You can see what this means below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#goHome').click(function(){
    window.location.replace('/');
})


url.py
(r'^$', main_page),
```